# Best intranet solution for a small digital agency?

Tags: intranet

I work for a small digital agency (10-15 employees).  We design and build websites (using php and Django).  Are we better off building our own intranet using django or going for a pre built (free or paid for) solution?

Key features needed:

- Project management (basecamp clone)
- Time reporting
- Local and external file sharing (dropbox clone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the nature of your business I would say build it yourselves.

This will give your team practice and experience in the products and technologies that you sell.

You'll probably learn some new techniques too!

Comment: Thanks, just worried we can't build it in time and on budget!

Comment: I have to agree here. Even today, almost 3 years later, I'd say there's nothing free you can really use without building up. And there's basically nothing paid that will be worth it for a company with 10-25 employees.